# How to set StyleClass for MenuItem from AppShell programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want so create my own MenuItems in the AppShell, this is working for me, but now I want to add StyleClass to this MenuItems. I have a StylClass Resource for MenuItems in the AppShell. If I add a MenuItem in AppShell.xaml I can use it without any problem, but my question is, how to that for my on created MenuItems in the code bind.

AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
private static MenuItem CreateMenuItem(string title, ICommand cmd)
        {
            var menuItem = new MenuItem
            {
                Text = title,
                Command = cmd,
                //Set StyleClass here
                
            };
            return menuItem;
        }
```

How can I use the StyleClass from the Sheel.Resources in the code behind?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, define one style for Menuitem, like this:

```
<Style Class="menuitemstyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="100" />
    </Style>
```

Then add one MenuItem by code behind in AppShell.cs and use style from Shell.Resources.

```
 public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Text="test 1",StyleClass=new[] { "menuitemstyle" } });

         
    }
```

Finally, you can get the screenshot:

[image]